# How to find accuracy of Matlab's quadprog solver?

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have solved with quadprog from Matlab a strong convex quadratic problem given as
$$ f(x) = x^TQx + c^Tx$$
with constrains
$$ Cx \leq b.$$

Now the output of quadprog is:

> Minimum found that satisfies the constraints.
>
> Optimization completed because the objective function is
>   non-decreasing in  feasible directions, to within the default value of
>   the function tolerance, and constraints are satisfied to within the
>   default value of the constraint tolerance.
>
> Optimization completed: The relative dual feasibility, 9.711779e-12,
>   is less than options.TolFun = 1.000000e-08, the complementarity
>   measure,
>   9.481207e-09, is less than options.TolFun, and the relative maximum constraint violation, 2.273737e-12, is less than options.TolCon =
>   1.000000e-08.
>
> Optimization Metric                                         Options
>   relative dual feasibility =   9.71e-12             TolFun =   1e-08
>   (default) complementarity measure =   9.48e-09               TolFun = 
>   1e-08 (default) relative max(constraint violation) =   2.27e-12
>   TolCon =   1e-08 (default)

What is now the accuracy of my computed solution $x^*$? I have found that TolFun is the size of the latest change in objective function value, and TolCon is the constraint tolerance.

At http://www.mathworks.de/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html I found that the default termination tolerance on x is $1e-08.$ Is this also used as a stopping criteria? Does it imply that my computed solution differs from the real solution only in $1e-08$?

I also do not understand how the computer can find a upper bound for the difference between my computed solution and the real solution.

Comment: I'm not sure about this particular algorithm, but you can bound the error by duality and use that as a stopping criterion. This is quite standard practice.